# Two strings combined into a keyword

Tags: string

I have a table in my database that records chat messages, I have two fields, `send_id` and `recv_id`, that records the sender and receiver.

How to design a function to generate a tag so that

```
func(send_id,recv_id)==func(recv_id,send_id)
```

is used to identify the same conversation.

Comment: Please edit your question and give us more context. What database are you using, what are you using to process data? I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please specify what language you are using. And as much as possible put a tag in your question to know if it's php, javacript, or etc.